# How to write something on mobile's nvram?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, operating-system

I have very limited knowledge of Android NDK and I want to write something on NVRAM using NDK. I want to know:

- If it is possible to write on NVRAM
- If yes, then how (I didn't find anything on google)
- If no, then do I need to make a customized operating system or any other solution?

The main goal is to lock the phone on a particular band e.g:

- Lock LTE mode and then band 1 of LTE

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: It won't be possible using an Android app. But, I guess, for some devices, there are some applications on Winows to write to NVRAM.

Comment: I have added more information. Is it possible to lock a particular band on mobile using an android app?

Comment: If by 'lock a band' you mean that you don't want the phone to use that band, I don't think that's possible, but, I'd like to be corrected here. But, if you want to 'lock the phone to a particular band', I know it's possible with MTK Engineering mode, so, obviously, it's available on very limited MediaTek powered phones. As far as Qualcomm, I have never come acorss such a way and I have no idea about other processors. As far as writing an app to do this task, it mostly won't work very easily as can vary from device to device.

Comment: I want to lock the phone on a particular band but using an android app.

Comment: Not possible (at least as of now). A quick Google search helped me, but, all those methods are on PC and need root.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qtrun.QuickTest&hl=en Found that app for Qualcomm devices. Needs root, though.

Comment: App Url is not working.

Comment: Network Signal Guru is the name of the app and QTRUN Technologies is the developer. Find it on Play Store. If you can't see it, it might be region restricted.

Comment: I have downloaded this app and reviewing. Thanks.

Comment: I think this app is doing the band locking. So at least now I know that it is possible. But how?

Comment: Some thoughts: QTRUN Technologies has 1.find a way to write on NVRAM. 2.another method to acheive this.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea how that app's doing it. I'm not a programmer. You might try reverse engineering the app to find it.

Comment: Also, I think you've got it wrong. Locking to bands nas nothing to do with NVRAM as far as my knowledge goes. NVRAM has the IMEI information, etc. So, I don't think it's 'writing' to NVRAM. The only hardware part that users can write to using any Android app (with or without root, or even as a system app), is the internal storage.

Comment: Actually, we are using QXDM to do this task. QXDM write something on NVRAM to achieve the goal. So, I have asked this question to do the same in android app. QXDM written value is erased by Android OS on restart so we want some way to persist the value and it seems if android app is able to write that value then we can write value again even if android clears that value.

Comment: You might be true. But, is locking the band also the job of NVRAM?

Comment: As far as I know, Android reads NVRAM at some locations for some information to initiate the system settings and in our case, OS should read at an address of NVRAM where band settings are stored.

Answer (score -1):

You can lock your band user Network Signal Guru.  In fact once you download the tool you execute the following

1. Select Menu ---> Lock Bands ---> Select LTE
2. Choose which Bands 1,2,4,5,40 etc..
3. Click Ok ---> Select Menu again ---select Lock RAT
4. Select LTE --> select ok

The mobile radio will powercycle once or twice but then your Band and LTE preference is locked and saved.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically just like Network Signal Guru is doing it. In other words, I want to develop similar app :)